# Material tab layout not displaying correctly

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to make this login page.

[image: Login]

Here is my code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.app.findmystay.View.MarqueeToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_accent"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabText"
                        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I am getting is this -

[image]

1. How to align toolbar text with the back button?
2. How will the layout collapse on scrolling?

Comment: Why do you have custom toolbar? If you use the one from appcompat it'll be just a matter of setting the title.

Answer (score 0):

First try to enable *show layout bounds* in developer options in settings.

Check the layout of the  *title* (Log in or sign up in your case).

If it's the layout problem, then set title programmatically by using

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.id_of_toolbar_from_layout);
toolbar.setTitle("Login or SignUp");
```

And then add toolbar to layout like

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Better try that first. and let me know if it does not works. :)